# Posso usar este site para outros ramos de atividades e gerar um comunidade com ele?

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de usar este site como uma central de perguntas e respostas colaborativas para um grupo de pessoas e atividades específicas, é possível?

Comment: Também pode tentar criar um site próprio para outros assuntos dentro do processo existente: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Parece que estás a tentar criar uma "central de ajuda" para um determinado grupo de pessoas relativamente a HTML5 e relacionados. As perguntas são sempre bem vindas, mas tens que ter em conta que as respostas são facultadas por qualquer utilizador e não por um grupo restrito deles.

Answer (score 6):

Este especificamente não, mas existe o **[Área 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)**, que é o berço de sites como o nosso e se sua comunidade for grande o suficiente, pode até tentar conseguir promover a criação de um site próprio. Toda a rede Stack Exchange é baseada praticamente no mesmo sistema, e há sites sobre os mais diversos assuntos.

> Para conhecer os vários sites da rede Stack Exchange, **[clique aqui](http://stackexchange.com/sites)**.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que não.

Segundo o Tour

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas. Foi desenvolvido e é administrado por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de perguntas e respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para desenvolver uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta sobre programação.

Ou seja, se não for assunto relacionado a programação, então não se encaixa no propósito do Stack Overflow