# Gerar comunidade de produto de software através de perguntas auto respondidas é muito feio?

Tags: debate, responder-a-si-mesmo, autopromoção

Em um dos meus trabalhos, estou encarregado em, dentre outras atividades, gerar uma tração maior na comunidade para o conhecimento da plataforma [TotalCross](http://www.totalcross.com/). Além de desenvolvedor da plataforma, também sou um entusiasta dela. (E sim, um dia em que eu não tiver preguiça/vontade de procrastinar eu coloco isso no perfil)

Minha questão aqui se dá na parte de criar perguntas às quais eu já sei a resposta para chamar atenção da comunidade em geral para a plataforma. Percebo que muitas vezes os moderadores perguntam sobre assuntos que eles mesmos sabem a resposta. A estratégia normal do bigown em relação a perguntas que ele mesmo sabe a resposta, que cria para fazer base de conhecimento e movimentar a comunidade, é esperar que alguém a responda ou, caso não respondam, fornecer uma ótima resposta.

Esse comportamento é ruim, quando visa despertar uma comunidade aqui no SOpt? É visto com maus olhos? Ou na verdade depende de como for feita a pergunta? Se for bem quista, tem algum formato desejável?, como lançar a perguntar e esperar tanto tempo para responder?

Temos também um canal de comunicação no [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/issues), porém o foco dos tíquetes do gitlab são de outro contexto.

As críticas feitas em [Posso usar este site para outros ramos de atividades e gerar um comunidade com ele?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/626/64969) se referem ao fato do user2891 hipoteticamente tentar criar uma comunidade para algo não voltado à programação em si, algo que obviamente vou evitar por ser uma plataforma de programação; ter um espaço específico para dúvidas não relativas à programação ajuda a não cair em tentação quanto a isso.

O post [Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/64969) não se refere ao fato de ser algo feito para atrair a comunidade/ação secundária de autopromoção. Aparentemente, o posicionamento foi "deixe os votos dizerem se foi útil ou não"

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem. Você quer criar e responder suas próprias perguntas, mas relacionado com a **TotalCross**?

Comment: Sim. Se alguém postar uma resposta significativa, não colocaria a minha.

Comment: O foco seria coisas voltadas à programação, não coisas tipo "como faço o executável para Android?" ou "Minha chave de ativação não chegou"

Comment: Alguém mais sem ser você conseguiria responder essas perguntas? Pergunto isso pq não sei se você criou uma linguagem específica, uma IDE, um compilador, etc...

Comment: Se entendi bem, você quer transformar o SO em uma wiki da sua aplicação. Se for isso, não tenho certeza se é permitido.

Comment: A grosso modo é Java sem annotations de runtime. Um exemplo seria "qual a melhor maneira de se fazer uma arquitetura de sincronismo de informação entre app e servidor usando TotalCross para o lado mobile?". Aí no detalhamento eu explico as restrições de não ter annotations e outros detalhes da plataforma

Comment: A ideia seria perguntas desse nível: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191779/64969

Comment: @diegofm , perguntas desse tipo, de clientes nossos que tiveram esse tipo de problema, constituem wikização do SOpt?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ai já entra na questão perguntada pelo Randrade, sobre quem poderia responder estas questões. Mas o fato de perguntarem sobre alguma ferramenta(desde que não seja algo combinado), não vira merchan. Temos um usuario com um plugin famoso aqui, e as vezes surgem algumas perguntas no site, mas tem varias pessoas alem dele que responde.

Comment: Pensando bem, se a pergunta demonstrar uma necessidade plausível, que permita que outros possam sugerir formas alternativas alem da sua solução, creio que não haverá problema algum :)

Comment: @diegofm , sobre quem pode responder: o TotalCross existe desde 2009, sendo o sucessor direto do SuperWaba que existia antes mesmo de eu entrar na faculdade (SW foi criado em 2000). Então creio que temos uma base de usuários já calejados, talvez eles parem por aqui.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Olhando o site, notei que [já possuímos 11 perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=totalcross) onde a palavra TotalCross aparece. Se não teve problemas em nenhuma delas, eu acho que não tem problema também. Acho que poderia até ser interessante apontar as perguntas em sua pergunta, com a finalidade de ajudar as pessoas a olharem melhor o que você está propondo

Comment: @Randrade são [3 perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=totalcross+is%3Aquestion), os demais são respostas ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu queria referir 11 posts. Valeu pela correção :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não posso falar por todos.

Gerar conhecimento é uma coisa, fazer propaganda de algo que "ninguém" quer saber é *spam*.

Eu diria pra fazer um teste e ver se há adesão.

Já que fui citado tenho que dizer que o que eu faço par de pergunta e resposta costuma ter vários votos, várias visitas e em geral é um assunto de interesse geral de toda comunidade ou uma sub-comunidade importante. Em geral pergunto sobre terminologia, engenharia de software, computação em geral e C. A [menos visitada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191748/101) foi vista por 31 pessoas até esse momento, eu achei que seria mais porque é algo que as pessoas vivem com essa dúvida. As menos votadas ([1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192041/101), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101), [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174312/101)) também são de C e tiveram várias visitas, sei lá porque acharam que não merecia votos até por serem de assuntos que valem até para quem não programa em C. Todas com poucas visitas são recentes, vai melhorar.

Se quiser fazer do SOpt um canal oficial de suporte ao produto em português, é mais que adequado, porque aí a demanda é real.

Eu não acho que seja um problema só uma pessoa poder responder, acho que o problema é zero pessoas estarem interessadas nisto.

As pessoas vão procurar no Google por algo e vão achar o SOpt? Ou será que apenas quem casualmente esbarrar nela aqui no SOpt é que saberá que isto existe?

Obviamente que todas as outras regras se aplicam.

Conteúdo é bom, *spam* não é. Então depende. Tenta e fique atento à reação. Vai devagar.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado pelo posicionamento. Muito esclarecedor. Ocasionalmente farei um piloto para ver se traz tração. Vou esperar mais um pouco enquanto outras pessoas contribuem